# Which user attribute can I use to mark "user type"?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there an attribute/property on user in both AD and AAD that we can use to mark "user type"? Our need is to use user object as a placeholder for a feature in our product, but we want to distinguish these special users from regular ones. Currently we're using CompanyName or Department but that's kind of hacky, so is there a better choice for us?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Active Directory has built in RBAC (role based access control) functionality, and it is probably best that you create custom User Roles for your needs.

This should walk you through all you need to know:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-create-custom-roles-for-internal-external-users

You can create and access this role information using the Graph API here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/directoryroles-operations